# bundle install --without production ; still tries to install production gems

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm planning to use Phusion Passenger Enterprise for production, but was just going to use the open-source `passenger` gem for development to test things out and get it running.

I set up my `Gemfile` like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "passenger", ">= 5.0.25", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"
end

group :production do
  gem "passenger-enterprise-server", ">= 5.0.25", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"
end
```

But when installing for development, it always wants to install `passenger-enterprise-server` ...

```
$ bundle install --without production
  Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
  Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
  Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
  Resolving dependencies...
  Could not find gem 'passenger-enterprise-server (>= 5.0.25) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.

$ more .bundle/config
  ---
  BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundler still needs to get the gemspec for all gems listed, and compare them all for compatibility, even with `--without` -- it won't actually *install* `passenger-enterprise-server`, but still needs to look up it's .gemspec to check compatibility.

And it can't find it for some reason. Probably because it's a license-protected limited access thing.

I'd ask Passenger support how they suggest you handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Try `bundle install --without=production`
[source](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html)

Update: Also, try installing the gem on your machine with `gem install` first, then run `bundle install` in your project.

Comment: Unfortunately, same result :( Also the bundler page on groups shows using spaces: http://bundler.io/v1.3/groups.html